# invoke method of class from jar using reflection

Tags: java, class, reflection, jar, invoke

I want to invoke a method from class which is inside an external jar using reflection. But I am still not able to do it. I'm using the following code

```
public class Test {
  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    try {
      // File JarFile = new File("C:\\dataRetrieval.jar");
      //
      // URLClassLoader cl = new URLClassLoader(new
      // URL[]{JarFile.toURI().toURL()});
      // JarFile.getClass();

      DataRetrievalManagerServiceStub stub = new DataRetrievalManagerServiceStub(
           "html//...............???wsdl");
      Map<String, String> requestMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
      requestMap.put("TelephoneNumber", "01028824332");


      Object stubInstance = Class.forName("com.test.DataRetrievalManagerServiceStub").newInstance();
      Object reqInstance = Class.forName("com.test.impl.GetOllehIdsForUserDocumentImpl").newInstance();




      Method[] stubMethods = stubInstance.getClass().getMethods();
      Method[] reqMethods = reqInstance.getClass().getMethods();
      //Method[] resMethods = resInterface.getClass().getMethods();
      for (Method method : reqMethods) {
        String methodName = method.getName();
        System.out.println(methodName);

      }


      for (Method method : reqMethods) {
        String methodName = method.getName(); 
        if (methodName.startsWith("set")) {
          methodName = methodName.replace("set", "");
          String value = null;
          if (requestMap.containsKey(methodName)) {
            value = requestMap.get(methodName);
          }
          method.invoke(reqInstance, value);
        }
      }
     Object resInterface = Class.forName(
          "com.test.GetOllehIdsForUserResponseDocument").getInterfaces();


    } catch (AxisFault e) {
      // TODO Auto-generated catch block
      e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
      // TODO Auto-generated catch block
      e.printStackTrace();
    }

  }
}
```

I get an error message shown below:

```
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.apache.axis2.description.AxisOperation). log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.InstantiationException: com.kt.sdp.impl.GetOllehIdsForUserDocumentImpl 
at java.lang.Class.newInstance0(Unknown Source) 
at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Unknown Source) at sdk.kt.com.Test.main(Test.java:78)
```

Does anyone have any idea?

Comment: You sent too much and too less. Send full stack trace. The jar structure is not interesting. And send the line code that produces the exception. Probably 5 lines before.

Comment: You cut the line with the error, give us the full trace.

Comment: InstantiationException mean you call newInstance on a class with no public contructor having no prarmaters. Read javaDoc of newInstance for more information. Or an exception is thrown while instantiation.

Comment: OP already has that question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16806973/invoke-method-from-jar-using-reflection

Comment: what does this mean "I hadn't win proper class" ?

Comment: @Rudy I don't know so I left it unedited. I corrected where I could :)

Comment: Not sure what you want to achieve here, but the idea with the URLClassLoader was perhaps the right one. However, you have to set your new Classloader as current classloader before you can instantiate classes from it. Something along `Thread.currentThread().setContextClassLoader(cl)`

Comment: @Rudy i mean, when i typing " method.invoke(reqInstance, value);" , i won different result. i think not invoking method from class.

Comment: @Djon error full trace>>log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.apache.axis2.description.AxisOperation). log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly. Exception in thread "main" java.lang.InstantiationException: com.kt.sdp.impl.GetOllehIdsForUserDocumentImpl at java.lang.Class.newInstance0(Unknown Source) at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Unknown Source) at sdk.kt.com.Test.main(Test.java:78)

Comment: @AlexR error full trace>>log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.apache.axis2.description.AxisOperation). log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly. Exception in thread "main" java.lang.InstantiationException: com.kt.sdp.impl.GetOllehIdsForUserDocumentImpl at java.lang.Class.newInstance0(Unknown Source) at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Unknown Source) at sdk.kt.com.Test.main(Test.java:78)

Comment: @GyroGearless i don't understand set new Classloader, i need detail comment

Comment: After reading for the second time it seems that the word that you are searching for is "got/get" and not "won". will update this in the question

Comment: @kkoyu please delete these comments and add the formated trace to your post, it's unreadable here.

Comment: @Djon edited the post. Formatted stack trace is up

Comment: @Rudy she is trying to say `want`. *I won* means *I want* :)